# Bounding $L^2$ operator norm of integral kernel

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Say I have an integral operator $T$ with $g\in L^2$ such that
$$\int |Tg(\xi)|^2d\xi=\int g(x)\overline{g(y)}K_1(x,y)\,dxdy.$$
Is it correct that then, by repeated Cauchy-Schwarz, we have that
$$\| Tg\|_{L^2}\le \|g\|_{L^2} \|K_1\|^{1/2}_{L^2}?$$

Comment: Yes, indeed, this is correct.

Comment: Why repeated ? You can apply the inequality just once  in the space $L^2(\mathbb{R}^2).$